# How to show if no data using php

Tags: php

I want to ask a question.i want to show data in table from database..it works but if no data in database, how i can show "there is no data yet"
this is my code :

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Test Name</th>
<th>Test Description</th>
</thead>

<?php while ($rec2= mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rec2['testName'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec2['testDesc'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

if(mysql_num_rows($result2)>0)
{

?>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Test Name</th>
<th>Test Description</th>
</thead>

<?php while ($rec2= mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rec2['testName'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec2['testDesc'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
<?php

}
else
{
?>
    NO DATA FOUND 
<?php
}
?>
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result2)==0)
   echo "Nothing" ;
```

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You check if your query return a result before fetching it:

```
if($result2){
    //fetch $result here
}
else{
    echo "there is no data yet";
}
```

Comment: That will be `false` only on an error. And `0 rows`  is not an error; hence that check will not work

Comment: A downvote 2 seconds after posting the answer. I should call guiness.

Comment: If the query executed fine and there are 0 rows in the result, it will still go to your `if` section

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I thought that was the point: if the OP wants to know if the table is empty he/she will have to addapt his/her query accordingly `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable`.

Comment: Fair enough. `SELECT COUNT(*)` will also work you are right but then it requires another query. `mysql_num_rows` will do both things in one query. But my point is that if this solution is used as it is and there are 0 rows in the result (provided query doesnt have errors) user will not see the message "there is no data yet"

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky `mysql_num_rows` will return the number of rows that the query got, so if the query is `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = 'something'` for example, that will mean that there is any entry that meets that cryteria, not that the table is necesarily empty. My answer is wrong though. I know that. I got confused because I'm used to having a class to perform the queries and I forgot that I set up the method to return false when there is a `$result = 0`. Still was funny the quick downvote. I hit the submit button and a second later -1 lol.

Comment: I'll be honest, that was me. After this discussion i believe the down-vote is no longer necessary. Just removed it. Cheers :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Thankyou. I know when I make a mistake. And if an answer is wrong, it doesn't bother me. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(mysql_num_rows($result2)==0)
   echo "Nothing to Display" ;
else
{
?>
<table>
<?php 
while ($rec2= mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $rec2['testName'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $rec2['testDesc'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}//end while loop
?>
</table>
<?php
}//ending if-else
?>
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain what your code does? That will help more SO users in the world. :)